# Next badge does not propose getting informed uninformed beginners

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The new "Next badge" entry on the activity profile page proposes to beginners the "Supporter" badge instead of the "Informed" badge.  Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189647/john-smith?tab=topactivity).

Comment: He does have some rep already, so you could argue that him learning about his new voting privilege is more important than reading the tour.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET sure but don't we want them to read about how to use these new privileges before using them?

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, but that information is primarily on the privilege description, which perhaps the tag popup should link to.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Where should a beginner learn about voting? That's what the tour is for.

Comment: The tour basically says "upvoted content rises to the top" and doesn't get into any details. This page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up is far more useful

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I will conceded the fact that the voting page is more detailed to that privilege, as it should be. The tour page has links to all of those things and covers the basics such as editing and what kind of questions to ask. As far as I'm concerned, that should be the next badge for anyone who hasn't read it.

Comment: It's questions like these that make me wish we had a "meh" vote in addition to upvoting and downvoting.

Comment: arguably the `informed` badge should persistently remain the next badge for any user until they have achieved it.